# Relative redirection in Python tornado

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

I have a tornado web app that would redirect users back to main page ("/" of the app). Then the `tornado` web app is deployed using nginx as the one of the app (e.g. www.helloworld.com/app) the redirection no longer works. The table below should describe the situation.

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Root URL of tornado app     | www.helloworld.com/app          |
| Redirect URL                | www.helloworld.com/app/redirect |
| Expected URL after redirect | www.helloworld.com/app          |
| Actual URL after redirect   | www.helloworld.com              |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Here is my RedirectHandler

```
class RedirectHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect(self.reverse_url("index"))
```

And here is my Application

```
handlers = [
            tornado.web.url(r'/', IndexPageHandler, name='index'),
            tornado.web.url(r'/redirect', RedirectHandler, name='redirect'),
        ]
```

Comment: Why do you expect to land on `/app` when you're actually redirecting to `/`?

Comment: Actually the apps is deployed in www.helloworld.com/app by nginx. But the tornado app itself doesn't know the location of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado is not designed for use with proxies that strip off a prefix of the URL. Configure your Tornado servers with full URLs (`tornado.web.url(r'/app', IndexPageHandler, name='index')`) and remove the path from your nginx `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I understand your point but the server owner and app developer is under two teams.

If tornado is couldn't do this are there any other alternatives? I would live to hear more :)

Comment: I don't know; I've never worked on a project that had this requirement. If nginx removes the `/app/`, it should be responsible for adding it back. It looks like there's a `proxy_redirect` option for this.